# Trying to extract public key from private key, and then validate the associated certificate

Tags: c++, c, ssl, encryption

I realize similar questions have been addressed elsewhere, on SO and on people's web pages. However, these solutions do not work. I have tried all of them, in various combinations, after my solo attempts failed.

Background: 
I have a file containing a private key (typically RSA), a CSR, and a X509 client certificate. These structures are all in PEM form. Users are supposed to concatenate these three components into a single file. Sometimes they don't, or do it improperly - for example, they'll omit the private key, or put the certificate in twice, or respin the private key without updating the certificate. I would like to detect these situations at system startup and point out to the user why they aren't going to contact the key manager server.

Problem: 
Primarily, I want to verify that the certificate corresponds to the private key. Of secondary interest is that the CSR corresponds to the certificate/private key.

The OpenSSL 'rsa' and 'x509' command line utilities indeed verify my sample test file, and that same file does allow my client to contact the key manager servers. These are fairly good validity indications.

Inspecting the OpenSSL module 'rsa.c', I see that the 'pubout' parameter winds up calling - I think - PEM_write_bio_RSA_PUBKEY. In OpenSSL 1.0.2f and OpenSSL 1.1.0, there is no source code I can find for PEM_write_bio_RSA_PUBKEY...yet rsa.c evidently compiles and links, and the VS debugger takes me into some assembly code, all of which suggests this is some sort of dynamically manufactured routine that the linker is plumbing in; if true, this doesn't seem particularly 'open source' to me, but there you go. Keep in mind that the structures don't have to be manually extracted from the consolidated file for the OpenSSL utilities to work - the utilities figure out what's of interest to them in a file (whether rsa, req, or x509) and that's what they play with.

Implementation:
The routine 'X509_verify' requires an X509 structure and an EVP_PKEY structure. The EVP_PKEY structure is supposed to be the public key (although one of the web pages I referenced has the author claiming it's a private key, which *might* work as RSA keys are interchangeable, as long as they're consistently interchanged...but as I can't get what's supposed to work, to work, I can't say one way or the other).

If 'X509_verify(...)' is to be used when all one has is a private key and certficate, the public key must be extracted from the private key, and supplied to 'X509_verify(...)' in an EVP_PKEY structure.

Here's one of the many, many ways I've tried this. This one actually gets to the X509_verify call with non-null pointers, but unhappily always returns a
zero from the verify. I skip over the CheckError calls, null checks and various 'free's:

```
//  Retrieve the BIO allocated earlier for the file, and
//  extract the private key...

EVP_PKEY * pPKEYPrivateKey = PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey(GetBIO(), NULL, NULL, NULL);    

int type = EVP_PKEY_type(pPKEYPrivateKey->type);

switch (type)
{
    case EVP_PKEY_RSA:
    case EVP_PKEY_RSA2:
    {
        //  Convert the EVP_PKEY private key structure to an
        //  RSA private key, then check it...

        RSA * pRSAPrivateKey = EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA(pPKEYPrivateKey);

        if (1 != RSA_check_key(pRSAPrivateKey))
        {
            ...no good, exit, stage right...
        }

        //  Using the RSA private key, extract and copy the
        //  public key into its own RSA structure...

        RSA * pRSAPublicKey = RSAPublicKey_dup(pRSAPrivateKey);

        //  Get a PKEY area...

        EVP_PKEY * pPKEYPublicKey = EVP_PKEY_new();

        //  Convert the public RSA key data into a EVP_PKEY structure...  

        int evtrc = EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA(pPKEYPublicKey, pRSAPublicKey);

        //  We now have the public key extracted into an EVP_PKEY
        //  structure (or do we?)...

        int verifyrc = X509_verify(ipCertificate->GetX509(), pPKEYPublicKey);

        //  ...but the above call always returns zero...

        if (1 != verifyrc
        {
    ...
```

An optimum solution would be key-type agnostic, where I don't have to distinguish between RSA or DSA, PEM or DER, or anything else. However, segregation of the various key types and formats is as close as I can get to the X509_verify call with something looking like a valid public key pointer. The workaround of comparing modulus values is just that - because, if that's how things are supposed to be verified, why are there X509 verify functions? Sure, the verify function itself might be comparing the modulus values...in which case, whether or not modulus values should be checked is irrelevant to the discussion at hand.

I've used the RSA_PUBKEY functions but these always return a null pointer. Since I don't know what they're doing, I can't figure out what's wrong.

An alternative is to extract the public key from the X509 certificate and compare it to the public key extracted from the private key, but that also seems like a workaround. Plus, if I'm not doing something right to start with, I'm no further ahead.

On the other hand, the perfect is the enemy of the good.

Summary:
One would think that this is not blazing a trail of any sort, and that this is pretty much a run-of-the-mill everyday sort of programmatic check - does this private key go with this X509 certificate? Even what I do have seems way too convoluted for something so mundane.

If someone is kind enough to provide a solution, please check it first. Trust but verify.

And: if someone can point me at the PEM_write_bio_RSA_PUBKEY source code, or PEM_write_bio_PUBKEY source code for that matter, I suspect that might clear up some of my confusion. Perhaps.

Thanks.

Comment: Is that C or C++? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: You don't need to extract the public key from the private key. You need to sign something with the private key, get the public key from the *certificate*, and see if the signature verifies with it.

Comment: If users are doing it wrong then you are asking them wrong. Capture and upload the pieces separately.

Comment: Why are users providing you with their private key? You do understand that it therefore ceases to be private? And is now useless?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. OpenSSL is C, of course, and what I'm

Comment: Try this again...Thank you for your comments. I see there are space limitations...

Comment: @Olaf: OpenSSL is C, of course, and what this is contained in, is C++. I'd prefer to avoid putting in all the classes and such. For example, the GetX509 returns an X509 OpenSSL structure (obviously for the certificate); the GetBIO returns an already created BIO source/sink structure, and I allocate a BIO for both the private key and certificate. Everything except for this particular check works. Mostly I was looking for guidance on the proper mechanism for programmatically checking private key vs. certificate; I assumed this was a well-known process, just not so well-known to me.

Comment: @EJP: It's the seeing that's the problem. As I mentioned, I've tried several approaches; the one above the one that got to the verify without a null pointer. I believe the x509_verify does compare the public key in the certificate with whatever EVP_PKEY structure it's fed. Manufacturing 'something', signing it with the private key, and trying that is...roundabout. It seems like everything I need is here. Still, my way doesn't work, so it doesn't make any difference how straightforward it is.

Comment: I believe the _PUBKEY call in rsa.c would be helpful as that's the rsa pubout option does, if only I could identify where it actually is.

Comment: @EJP: When done correctly, as most users do, they create a CSR with their private key, put on their CA hat and sign the CSR, put client stuff into the single file, and then they're set, client credential-wise. This code resides in the client and is part of client initialization. These checks are one of the typical ways users (i.e., clients) go astray. As this connection is TLS, both ends authenticate, as you know. Well, usually both ends do.

Comment: @stark: The private key, CSR, and certificate are concatenated for portability and coherence. Think of it as a simple keystore. This is a means to help keep the right private key with the right CSR and the right certificate. I could load them separately, but then I'd get even more instances of mismatches. For example, a user created a key on linux, cut and paste into windows to create a CSR, back to linux to have the CA sign it: the private key & certificate didn't agree. Line termination characters.

Comment: If some of my commentary doen't flow logically, it's because I had to chop out the connecting thoughts. I hope the salient points are present, though.

Comment: One last item: The user (people) initially set a client system up with client credentials {private key, CSR, and certificate}, and a CA certificate. The certificates all have expiration dates, as you know. The system is started. Months go by...Say, for example, the client (or CA, or both for that matter) certificate approaches its expiration date, and the user (people) use the CSR to respin their certificate. Or, perhaps they've rekeyed. Or changed their DN. I dunno: something. Nevertheless, I have to validity check what's there initially and on triggering events.